# How to search a file from a folderA and move to folderB using unix script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

How to search a file starts with SP and ends with .txt  from a folderA and move to folderB by adding current date to the files

and delete the files from folderB if files are older than one week. using unix script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to mv SP....txt files from folder A to folder B.

```
mv `find A -type f -name SP*.txt` B
```

As for your 2nd requirement, where u need the date? inside the files or in the filename?

Comment: Careful - that'll break in certain circumstances. (Files with spaces in them, for example).

Answer (score 0):

```
SrcDir="folderA";
DestDir="folderB";
cd "$SrcDir";
dt=$(date +%Y-%m-%d);
for file in    SP*.txt
do  cp  "$file" "$DestDir/${file%.*}_$dt.txt";    
done
```

Comment: This code doesn't do what you think it does. SrcDir and DestDir both contain relative paths, so after you `cd` `cp` won't copy to the proper folder.  Also, you've neglected the stuff about deleting old files from folderB.